# GitHub repository names not updated in "Public Activity" tab

Tags: github

Recently I have made a large cleanup to all my repositories -- I have migrated / transferred most of then to a different GitHub organizations and also did a lot of renaming stuff.

When I visit "[Contributions](https://github.com/trejder)" tab of my public GitHub profile, everything is fine. But, when I visit "[Public activity](https://github.com/trejder?tab=activity)" tab, I can clearly see, that all entries points to "incorrect" / base / previous GitHub accounts and repository names.

Is this a bug or by design and if latter, then what is the reason behind this?

GitHub correctly keeps all redirections, so clicking on all links in "Public activity" won't end up with 404, but will lead the clicker to the correct place. But, even so, I still wonder, why all these entries are not updated on "Public activity" tab, while they are updated on "Contributions" tab?

Answer (score 0):

I have received a lightning-fast response (seems, it is sometimes possible) from GitHub support.

It says:

> We intentionally don't update your public activity feed entries, but we certainly appreciate that this would be helpful. I'll pass this on to the team working on this area of GitHub.com as a reminder.

So, this isn't a bug, but rather should be possessed as by design. However, GitHub is aware, that this is at least *strange* and we may expect, that this will be *fixed* soon or later.